# Remove double quotes from nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove double quotes from nested array data

```
["[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]"]
```

To this array

```
[[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]]
```

using javascript

Comment: The latter presumes that there are variables a-g to include as values in the array of arrays. Is this really what you have? And what are you trying to achieve...?

Comment: I assume that `a, b, c` etc are placeholders for something. Or if not: *the literal string `[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]` is NOT valid JSON*.

Comment: You are actually looking at a one dimensional array containing only a string. You could convert this string to array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need valid values for the `a, b, c` etc, without that this makes no sense *and* it will not even be possible.

One way is to construct a valid JSON string and parse it, as follows:

```js
var arr = ["[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]"];
var json = "{ \"x\" : [" + arr[0] + "] }";
console.log(json);
var res = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(res.x);
console.log(res.x[0]);
console.log(res.x[1]);
console.log(res.x[2]);
```

Another way is to use `eval()`:

```js
var arr = ["[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]"];
var res = eval("[" + arr[0] + "]");
console.log(res);
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2]);
```

**Please Note - `eval()` is considered dangerous because it will execute just about any javascript that you may get fed (it is not limited to static object data in the same way that JSON.parse() is).**

---

**Update** - If you *must* use the literal `a,b,c` etc. then those names have to exist as pre-defined variables in your code, and then you can use only `eval()` because `eval()` runs in the scope of your program, whereas JSON.parse() does not.

Example:

```js
var a = 1,
  b = "hello",
  c = new Date(),
  d = ["p", "q", "r"],
  e = 5,
  f = new Object(),
  g = 7;
var arr = ["[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[e,f,g]"];
var res = eval("[" + arr[0] + "]");
console.log(res);
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
console.log(res[2]);
```

Comment: why `{"x": [`? this works just fine: `JSON.parse('[' + arr[0] + ']')`

Comment: it is giving error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2
at JSON.parse.

Comment: **@jcubic** I see that you are right, I always assumed that JSON.parse needed `{ "key" : value }` to work. So that's a third way, in between my two variants. Thanks for helping. **@ksanjay** please specify which variant you tried to get that output.

Comment: @jcubic thanks for your answer but i jst want to access this array like [[a,b,c],[b,c,d]] so that i can more items into it from my input field

Comment: @ksanjay `arr = JSON.parse('[' + arr[0] + ']'); arr.push([10,11,12]);` you will get `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]];`

Comment: and if you want inner array you can use `arr[0].push(x) arr[1].push(x);`